# How to store password in portable way?

Tags: c#, security, password-protection

I'm developing simple Twitter reader and I came across following problem: How to securely store the OAuth `consumer-key` and `consumer-secret`. Those two passwords are necessary for accessing the Twitter API, but those should be transparent to user.

I was looking at CryptoAPI, DPAPI and encrypted config file, but those will work only for local machine, as they are bound to logged user or specific machine.

So the question is, how to store application level sensitive info in portable way?

Comment: Are you developing for Windows, Windows Phone, or something else?  What do you mean by portable?

Comment: I'm developing on Windows. In portable way I mean in such way I can safely distribute my app, with my `consumer-key` and `consumer-secret` passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

If there is communication happening between your server and the client, you can use session keys to encrypt/decrypt the secret data.

OR

1. Create a key pair (RSA) or get in touch with Certificate Authority
2. Encrypt the secret  keys
3. Send them via n/w
4. Let the client get access to your key
5. Client will decrypt the secret data

Comment: This solution will work in general case, so I'll mark it as accepted. Although, in my particular case, I don't have any other connection than to Twitter, so it is not suitable for my case. Either way, you solution is probably the best option.

Comment: Agreed. If you do not have any other connection, then it is tough to ensure the secrecy of the keys in transit.